# I need to find the movie name and their average rating in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection name movies and I inserted the data having some popular movies data like release date and name of director and movieID.

I have inserted data from another table into the same collection movieId showed for which movie user submitted the review.

Now the question is I have to find the title and average rating of each movie.Here is only one movie data on which user reviewed.

```
db.movies.insert([
  {
    Movie_ID: 1,
    MovieName: 2001,
    Director: "Stanley Kubrick",
    Leading_Actors: [
      "Daniel Richter",
      "Gary Lockwood",
      "Keir Dullea",
      "William Sylvester"
    ],
    Release_Date: 1968,
    Oscar_Won: 1,
    Country: "USA"
  }
]);

db.movies.insert([
  {
    Movie_ID: 1,
    ReviewedBy: "Joe",
    Date: "6/15/2018",
    Rating: 9,
    Comments: "The best ever!"
  },
  {
    Movie_ID: 1,
    ReviewedBy: "Howie",
    Date: "6/9/2018",
    Rating: 7
  }
]);
```

I tried but failed.I need movie name which I think will be get by the movie ID and then avg() is applied to the ratings column. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
db.movies.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$Movie_ID",AvgRate:{$avg:"$Rating"}}}]);
```

But I got movieId because I used _id as Movie_ID but I need Names of the movies. And Yes, I'm using the command line or shell version of mongo db 4.1

Comment: Both are `movies` collection? Because one collection contains `MovieName` and one contains `Rating`... Are they same ?

Comment: I have to insert the data into a single collection which is "movies"

Comment: With adding `Ratings` and `Comments` fields? What is the collection name? And do you want to update or aggregate?

Comment: aggregate because i have to find the average "Ratings" of the movies given by the user to the particular movie

Comment: in this demo two user gave the rating to the Movie_ID "1" which is "2001" i have to find the average

Comment: Both collection have same name `movies`?

Comment: Yes both have same name(There is only one collection named movies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

`$match` to collect all documents where movie name is present followed by `$lookup` on movie id to get the ratings.

`$project` to keep the name and `$avg` to get movie average rating.

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"MovieName":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"movies",
    "localField":"Movie_ID",
    "foreignField":"Movie_ID",
    "as":"movie_rating"
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "MovieName":1,
    "AvgRate":{"$avg":"$movie_rating.Rating"}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Movie_ID",
    "AvgRate": { "$avg": "$Rating" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "movies",
    "let": { "movieId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$Movie_ID", "$$movieId" ] },
        "MovieName": { "$exists": true }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "movie"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Movie_ID": "$_id",
    "AvgRate": 1,
    "MovieName": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$movie.MovieName", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helps me to populate with the pipeline.